# How to delete rows if cells abide by if conditions

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have created a macro to delete entire row if a range of cells of the row abides by an if condition. The problem so far is that the macro is actually not deleting all the rows that should be deleted and I have no idea why. I have tested numerous times but no result. I should mention that the range is copy pasted from another worksheet, but I have already made this part work. So, I dont think there is a problem there. I am providing a screenshot of my excel sheet and the code below.

[image]

```
    Sub a()

Dim lastrow3 As Long

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Report_Copy"
    Worksheets("Report").Cells.Copy
    With Worksheets("Report_Copy")
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    With Worksheets("Report_Copy").UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Report_Copy")
    lastrow3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow3 To 25 Step -1
        Set cell = .Range("L" & i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 9)), "<0.5") = 10 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deleting rows you need to loop backwards.

Use the loop below and replace it with your last loop:

```
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Report_Copy")
    lastrow3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow3 To 25 Step -1
        Set cell = .Range("L" & i)
        If cell.Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 2).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 3).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 4).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 5).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 6).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 7).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 8).Value < 0.5 And cell.Offset(0, 9).Value < 0.5 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

**Note:** you can repalce your multiple cells condition with the same critera `<0.5` by using the `CountIf` function:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 9)), "<0.5") = 10 Then
```

Comment: It gives an error on Set cell = .Range("L" & i).Value saying type mismatch

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives the error in the same line... I am updating the code as it is after the changes...

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas how did you define `cell` ? is it `Range` ?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas you didn't copy my updated code, without the `.Value` at the end

Comment: Still it says there is a type mismatch in the same line.. I havent defined cell

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas use `Option Explicit`at the top of your code, this will help you find a lot of errors, Also define all your variables and objects

Comment: The only variable I have defined is the lastrow3. Which other should I define??

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas `Dim lastrow3 As long, i As Long, cell As Range`

Comment: Buddy thank you very much for all the help!! You were right ! Dim cell As Range and is perfect now! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When delete row index move to the next element in loop. If two rows meet the requirements lie next to each other, the bottom row will not be removed.

Use for next loop. Example removed all rows with value 1 in `range(A1:A4)`:

```
Public Sub test()
Dim cell As Range
For i = 1 To Range("A1:A4").Rows.Count
 Set cell = Range("a" & i)
    If cell = 1 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```